# How to validate the data with the line text to generate a different output file in perl

Tags: perl

I have a GMF file

```
TSTARTCUSTEVSUMMROW_SIMPLE
CUSTEVSUMMROW_SIMPLE Airtime - Simple All In Plan (Monthly)|3040|MOU|0|0
CUSTEVSUMMROW_SIMPLE Airtime - Simple All In Plan (Monthly)|1758|MOU|8000|140640
CUSTEVSUMMROW_SIMPLE Airtime - Simple All In Talk and Text Prepaid|3040|MOU|0|0
TENDCUSTEVSUMMROW_SIMPLE
TSTARTCUSTEVSUMMROW_GPRS_SIMPLE
CUSTEVSUMMROW_GPRS_SIMPLE GPRS - Simple All In Plan (Monthly) - LTE|2860|MB|6500|488
TENDCUSTEVSUMMROW_GPRS_SIMPLE
TSTARTCUSTEVSUMMROW_TF
CUSTEVSUMMROW_TF Airtime - TRCF2000Pkg|2952|MOU|8000|236160|
TENDCUSTEVSUMMROW_TF
TSTARTCUSTEVSUMMROW_GPRS_TF
CUSTEVSUMMROW_GPRS_TF GPRS - TRCF2000Pkg - LTE|13493|MB|6500|1496
TENDCUSTEVSUMMROW_GPRS_TF
```

I'm able to process the file successfully, with the below code.

```perl
if ( $line =~ m/^(CUSTEVSUMMROW_GPRS|CUSTEVSUMMROW).*?\s(.*?)\|(\d+)\|.*\|(.*?)$/ ) {
  # do some logic
}
```

where the single is generated for both TF and SIMPLE tags

Instead of using `elsif`, how can I modify the logic so that both `TF` and `SIMPLE` generate two different output files.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start by splittling the line on pipe characters `|`, and then process the first field in more detail

This program works that way. The record is split into the `@fields` array, and then the first element, `$fields[0]`, is removed and replaced with its constituent parts using `splice` together with a regex pattern

I have displayed the resulting value of `@fields` using `Data::Dump`. You can use the values for whatever you need. Clearly `$fields[1]` is `SIMPLE` or `TF` so you can alter your processing accordingly

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    next unless /^CUSTEVSUMMROW/;

    chomp;
    my @fields = split /\|/;
    splice @fields, 0, 1, $fields[0] =~ /(.+)_(\S+)\s+(.+)/;
    dd \@fields;
}

__DATA__
TSTARTCUSTEVSUMMROW_SIMPLE
CUSTEVSUMMROW_SIMPLE Airtime - Simple All In Plan (Monthly)|3040|MOU|0|0
CUSTEVSUMMROW_SIMPLE Airtime - Simple All In Plan (Monthly)|1758|MOU|8000|140640
CUSTEVSUMMROW_SIMPLE Airtime - Simple All In Talk and Text Prepaid|3040|MOU|0|0
TENDCUSTEVSUMMROW_SIMPLE
TSTARTCUSTEVSUMMROW_GPRS_SIMPLE
CUSTEVSUMMROW_GPRS_SIMPLE GPRS - Simple All In Plan (Monthly) - LTE|2860|MB|6500|488
TENDCUSTEVSUMMROW_GPRS_SIMPLE
TSTARTCUSTEVSUMMROW_TF
CUSTEVSUMMROW_TF Airtime - TRCF2000Pkg|2952|MOU|8000|236160|
TENDCUSTEVSUMMROW_TF
TSTARTCUSTEVSUMMROW_GPRS_TF
CUSTEVSUMMROW_GPRS_TF GPRS - TRCF2000Pkg - LTE|13493|MB|6500|1496
TENDCUSTEVSUMMROW_GPRS_TF
```

#### output

```
[
  "CUSTEVSUMMROW",
  "SIMPLE",
  "Airtime - Simple All In Plan (Monthly)",
  3040,
  "MOU",
  0,
  0,
]
[
  "CUSTEVSUMMROW",
  "SIMPLE",
  "Airtime - Simple All In Plan (Monthly)",
  1758,
  "MOU",
  8000,
  140640,
]
[
  "CUSTEVSUMMROW",
  "SIMPLE",
  "Airtime - Simple All In Talk and Text Prepaid",
  3040,
  "MOU",
  0,
  0,
]
[
  "CUSTEVSUMMROW_GPRS",
  "SIMPLE",
  "GPRS - Simple All In Plan (Monthly) - LTE",
  2860,
  "MB",
  6500,
  488,
]
[
  "CUSTEVSUMMROW",
  "TF",
  "Airtime - TRCF2000Pkg",
  2952,
  "MOU",
  8000,
  236160,
]
[
  "CUSTEVSUMMROW_GPRS",
  "TF",
  "GPRS - TRCF2000Pkg - LTE",
  13493,
  "MB",
  6500,
  1496,
]
```